# Disable truncation of events with React Big Calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

Events truncate if there are more events than can fit in a cell and you will notice "+X more" will show up:

[image]

How can i disable this feature and expand the cell so that every event shows? So the cell will expand with events.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This is intentional, to keep the calendar layout. You use the 'popup' to display complete list of events for that date.

http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-popup

Comment: given link is dead

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil Thanks. The project changed ownership, so their documentation site changed. I have updated the link.